# How to invert each subarray from a tensor in python?

Tags: python

I am looking for a computationally fast method to invert all sub-arrays of a tensor in python. So for example I have a tensor of shape (100,100,6,6)=(i,j,a,b) and I want to invert each sub-array at index (i,j) of shape (6,6)=(a,b) and write the inverse at the given index (i,j) in a new tensor.

```
tensor = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,100,6,6))

np.linalg.inv(tensor) # this does obviously not work, so I am looking for a fast method to invert each 6x6 subarray
```

I also need the method to throw an exception if one of the sub-arrays is not invertible.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the documentation again I noticed that numpy is able to invert tensors with numpy.linalg.inv the way I was looking for.

the last example of http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html#numpy.linalg.inv

Inverses of several matrices can be computed at once:

```
a = np.array([[[1., 2.], [3., 4.]], [[1, 3], [3, 5]]])

inv(a)
array([[[-2.  ,  1.  ],
        [ 1.5 , -0.5 ]],
       [[-1.25,  0.75],
        [ 0.75, -0.25]]])
```

So in my case this works, unless one of the sub-arrays is not invertible:

```
np.linalg.inv(tensor)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the indices of the array. [`numpy.linalg.inv`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html) does not provide an `axis` argument, so this will likely be the fastest method.

The function will raise an `np.linalg.LinAlgError` on failure to compute the inverse, so you can test for that.

```
import numpy as np

tensor = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(100, 100, 6, 6))
inverse = np.empty_like(tensor)

for i in range(tensor.shape[0]):
    for j in range(tensor.shape[1]):
        try:
            inverse[i, j] = np.linalg.inv(tensor[i, j])
        except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
            print(f"error on i={i}, j={j}")
            raise
```